# TypeError: this.itemRenderer is undefined Magento 2

Tags: knockout.js, magento2, magento-2.0

minicart.js file contains following code,

```
 getItemRenderer: function (productType) {
            return this.itemRenderer[productType] || 'defaultRenderer';
        }
```

but in my console showing following error,

```
TypeError: this.itemRenderer is undefined Magento 2
```

because of this i think magento mini cart is not working.
can anyone please tell me solution for this.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What is calling `getItemRenderer`, and how? Check what `this` is in there.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were changed the 'minicart' block to a different one.

Please make sure that the checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml (vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layou/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml) have the same block, in which the 'itemRenderer' was set.

Answer (score -1):

Delete Magento_Checkout/layout folder from your theme.